# Reading a file in chunks

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, file, io

I currently have the following class that takes a custom file object as an argument and makes a copy of the file locally.

```
class FileCopier
 def initialize(file_info_object)
  @file_info_object = file_info_object
 end

 def copy
  File.open(local_file_path, 'wb') do |f|
   read_file_in_chunks do |chunk|
     f.write chunk
   end
  end
 end

private

 def local_file_path
  File.join(Rails.root,'tmp/blah.txt')
 end

 def read_file_in_chunks(chunksize=10343)
  index = 0
  size = @file_info_object.size
  path = @file_info_object.path

  while index < filesize
   yield Client.read(path, offset: index, length: chunksize)
   index += chunksize
  end

 end

end
```

The copy method seems to be fairly straight forward but I was wondering if there is a way to simplify it. It seems difficult to test to me at the moment.

Comment: Could you tell us more about `CustomFileReader`?

Comment: I should have been more specific. My apologies. The CustomFileReader has now been renamed to 'Client'. Basically the client is an HDFS client that is reading from an HDFS directory. I am using the webHDFS gem for the client. [webHDFS gem](https://github.com/kzk/webhdfs)

Comment: One constraint I have is that I can't connect to HDFS locally. What would be a good way to test the export method? (Rspec 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes:

- Use 2-space indentation.
- `f.write chunk`. You use parens in other places, be consistent.

Other than these minor issues, I think your code is pretty good. I'd just refactor `read_file_in_chunks` to use a enumerator instead (more versatile) and a range.

```
def read_file_in_chunks(chunksize=10343)
  Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    (0...@file_info_object.size).step(chunksize).each do |offset|
      data = Client.read(@file_info_object.path, offset: offset, length: chunksize)
      yielder.yield(data)
    end
  end
end
```

Using lazy collections (Ruby >= 2.0) it can be simplified even more:

```
def read_file_in_chunks(chunksize=10343)
  (0...@file_info_object.size).step(chunksize).lazy.map do |offset|
    Client.read(@file_info_object.path, offset: offset, length: chunksize)
  end
end
```